# SSL .htaccess - Simple Q

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, ssl-certificate

I truly hate this file... I just spent 6.5 hours trying to figure this out and with my ADHD dyslexia it's just impossible!!
I have a domain that I bought for SSL for (currently I Have to wait for the ssl for WWW to kick in but for now the domain without WWW works, for example:

https://tomas.com

The .htaccess I have in root is currently:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} tomas\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://tomas.com/$1 [R,L]
```

And the code above does in fact activate SSL which is good. The thing is, I have a few files in root domain but one of them called is:

`hello.php`     *(located at:  "tomas.com/hello.php")*

If I go to:
http://tomas.com/hello
I want it to display that file (and in address bar it should say:  "http://tomas.com/hello").
Before the SSL I had this code below and it worked (but not anymore):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?(.*)$ $1.php
```

Any idea how the entire .htaccess is supposed to look like? :/

**I'm also same time trying to FORCE it to NOT use www (so if they do it should be redirected to a non WWW url)**
Thank you so much in advance!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: "I truly hate this file... ": simple, do not use it. Put your configuration in the main Apache configuration files. This improves security, performance and simplicity (clearer configuration). Of course depending on where and how your website is hosted you might not have access to Apache main configuration files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Before the SSL I had this code below and it worked (but not anymore):
>
> ```
> RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?(.*)$ $1.php
> ```

Not sure how this "worked" before, it's not complete by itself and does more that simply append a `.php` extension. You need something to prevent a rewrite loop, since `hello.php` also matches the pattern `^([^/]*)/?(.*)$`.

Try the following instead, *after* your HTTP to HTTPS redirect.

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

This first checks that the file with a `.php` file extension exists before internally rewriting to it.

**Alternatively**, you could instead just enable MultiViews if you aren't doing any other URL rewriting. For example, at the top of your file:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

This uses mod_negotiation to basically enable extensionless URLs for *everything*!

Comment: Mr White, any ideas for  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65015896
? :)