# htacces 2 variables issues

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, ssl-certificate

**BEFORE** I installed SSL things were working perfectly!! Here is the code I have in my root webserver .htaccess file:

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} andrea\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://andrea.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

It works and it does exactly what I want it to do. So if I go to for example:

```
www.andrea.com/account
```

it accesses "www.andrea.com/account.php". Which is what I want.
I do however have a folder in root called "products". There is another ".htaccess" file in that folder and I don't know which of these 2 must be changed to make the following thing below work.

When you go to this url:
http:____/products/**view**/Hello/Goodbye

I want it to access "view.php" in the 'products' folder and in that php file I could do this:

```
$id = $_GET["id"];    //      This would have "Hello"
$cat = $_GET["cat"];    //   This would have "Goodbye"
```

And this works well when I use this htaccess in the "products" folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?(.*)$ /products/view.php?id=$1&cat=$2
```

**The problem with this code above is, if I go to:**
http:____/products/Hello/Goodbye

I want it to access the "index.php" that is in "products" folder. But instead it goes to "view.php" instead!! It's like the htaccess code above forced all to go to view.php (which should only be done if I have the "view/____" in the url.
I want the url above to go to "index.php" in the "products" folder and in that file I should be able to access ID and CAT variables.

Any ideas of what to change in my .htaccess file? Sorry I spent over 2 hours I don't understand a single line at the bottom of my code but it doesn't work :/

Comment: Are you hosting multiple domains? What is the intention behind the first redirect in your `/products/.htaccess` file - this seems to conflict with the HTTP to HTTPS redirect in the root? In the URL `/view/Hello/Goodbye` - which parts are _optional_? Your directive implies that both `Hello` and `Goodbye` could be optional - but this isn't stated in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following rule to rewrite `/products/Hello/Goodbye` to `/products/index.php` .

```
RewriteRule ^Hello/GoodBye/?$ /product/index.php?id=hello&cat=Goodbye  [L,NC]
```

Here is your complete `/product/.htaccess` .

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
#rewrite /products/Hello/GoodBye to /products/index.php
RewriteRule ^Hello/GoodBye/?$ /products/index.php?id=Hello&cat=Goodbye  [L,NC]
###################
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?(.*)$ /products/view.php?id=$1&cat=$2
```

Comment: Amit thank you so much for replying !!!! :)
The “hello” and goodbye however are variables that needs to be free not set.  
In other words the url should be able to contain what ever.  Do u know what I mean?
I should be able to go to /products/4729/gold
Or: /products/view/silver
And I should be able to retrieve it with:

$id = $_GET["id"];   
$cat = $_GET["cat"];    

You able to by any chance provide me the full htaccess eirg that adjustment ? I can’t thank you enough.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  Options +MultiViews
> ```

First off, you should *disable* MultiViews. In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64830527/369434) to your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64828783/ssl-htaccess-simple-q), my suggestion to use MultiViews was strictly an "alternative" method in the context of your question. You cannot use both methods (mod_rewrite *and* MultiViews) to work with extensionless URLs. And since you are now wanting to do more things and pass parameters, MultiViews will only create conflicts. (MultiViews will likely "win" and no parameters get passed.)

Also, do you specifically need the additional `.htaccess` file in the `/products` subdirectory? It will be (arguably) easier to have a single `.htaccess` file in the document root. This will avoid having to repeat the HTTP to HTTPS redirect (although you've not actually included an HTTP to HTTPS redirect in the subdirectory `.htaccess` file?).

> ```
> # /products/.htaccess
> RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?(.*)$ /products/view.php?id=$1&cat=$2
> ```

This directive matches both `view/Hello/Goodbye` *and* `Hello/Goodbye`, which explains why everything is being written to your `view.php` script. However, it's not actually doing what you say either - which is puzzling. If you request `/products/view/Hello/Goodbye` then it will rewrite the request to `/products/view.php?id=view&cat=Hello/Goodbye` - which is not the intention (unless MutliViews is enabled, in which case no parameters will be passed at all).

You need to actually check for `views` in the requested URL-path before attempting to rewrite to `views.php`. And if `views` is not present then rewrite to `index.php` instead. This "conditional branching" can be achieved by simply arranging the directives in the order of "more specific" rules first.

For example, in your root `.htaccess` file try the following. (And remove the `/products/.htaccess` file altogether.)

```
# Ensure that MultiViews is disabled
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# HTTP to HTTPS canonical redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Abort early if the request already maps to (or looks like) a file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.\w{2,4}$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# 1. Rewrite "/products/view/<id>/<cat>" to "/products/view.php?id=<id>&cat=<cat>
RewriteRule ^(products/view)/([^/]*)/?(.*) $1.php?id=$2&cat=$3 [L]

# 2. Rewrite "/products/<id>/<cat>" to "/products/index.php?id=<id>&cat=<cat>
RewriteRule ^(products)/([^/]*)/?(.*) $1/index.php?id=$2&cat=$3 [L]

# 3. Extensionless URLs for other requests
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

The order of the 3 rules above is important. The most specific rule is first. Including the `L` flag to prevent further (unnecessary) processing.

Note that, as per your original directives, for a request of the form `/products/view/Hello/Goodbye` (or `/products/Hello/Goodbye`), the `Hello/Goodbye` part is entirely optional and will naturally result in the `id` and `cat` URL parameters being set, but empty.

Also, as per your original directives, a request of the form `/products/view/Hello/Goodbye/foo/bar/baz` will result in the `cat` URL parameter being set to `Goodbye/foo/bar/baz` (anything that follows the initial path segment).

You do not necessarily need to check that a request maps to a file or directory (which is relatively *expensive*) if you make your regex more specific and only match what you need to match. For example, your regex `/([^/]*)/?(.*)` currently match pretty much *anything*. But if your `<id>` and `<cat>` variables can only consist of lowercase letters (for example) then this could avoid the need for the filesystem checks.

Other notes:

- Do you need to check the hostname in the HTTP to HTTPS redirect? Do you host multiple domains? Otherwise the condition that checks against the `HTTP_HOST` server variable is not required.

Comment: MrWhite thank you first of all for your amazing msg. I truly appreciate all the time you put in to it.
I did exactly what you asked me to do, and EVERYTHING works perfectly fine, besides one thing. 
Regardless if I use "/products/view/200019/hejsan" or "/products/view/200019", variable ID and CAT both are empty when I try to _GET in view.php :(

Comment: I've tested this on my dev server and it works as intended (vars `id` and `cat` are both populated ok - with "200019" and "hejsan" respectively for that particular URL). To clarify, the code is _exactly_ as posted above? No other directives? `MultiViews` is _disabled_ with a `-` (not `+`) prefix? And you have no other `.htaccess` files, except for the `.htaccess` file in the document root of the site?

Comment: _Aside:_ I've made a very slight change to the code in my answer - I've removed the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` _susbtitution_ strings (two rules). However, I would not expect this to make any noticeable difference - more of a code tidy/optimisation.

Comment: "BEFORE I installed SSL things were working perfectly!!" - Just to add, these issues should not have anything to do with "installing SSL". Unless the SSL vHost has additional/different directives or `.htaccess` overrides were not enabled? But in that case I would expect a different response. Do you have access to the server config?

Comment: Also, make sure you've cleared your browser cache and are not seeing a cached response.

Comment: Mrwhite, I'm using exact code above that you edited. "/products/view/200019" gives blank in CAT variable. But, "/products/view/200019/test" however will put 'test' in the CAT variable. What I would want is for it to put "20019/test" in the CAT variable. Pretty much everything that is after "view/". 
So sorry for the inconvenience :(

Comment: Also, this doesn't force SSL and remove the www on the site :/